# SVN 1.9 Ubuntu 16.04 Installation - User Access Control -

Tags: svn, ubuntu-16.04

i have installed SVN on Ubuntu. If i try to access the SVN through HTTP without per-directory authentication(using only `dav_svn.passwd` inside `dav_svn.conf`) i can see the files in the repository correctly. But if i add `dav_svn.authz` inside `dav_svn.conf` to Control User Access, i can not access the repository. In `dav_svn.authz` i wrote only the following code:

```
[repo1:\]
* = rw
```

Am i doing something wrong? Is there anything else i need to do? Is the file ignored?